# Create a list of elements from a data frame

Tags: r, list, class, dataframe

I want to create a list of "classes" from a data frame. 
As an example,

```
set1=sample(LETTERS[1:7])
set2=sample(LETTERS[8:17])
set3=sample(LETTERS[18:26])

set_collection = list(class1=set1, class2=set2, class3=set3)
```

The problem is that my data is in a dataframe with two columns, with elements (letters in the example) in first column and classes (sets in the example) in the second column. I want the data to be in a structure like set_collection in the example above.

There are ~2000 such unique classes (second column) and ~20000 elements in those classes (in the first column).

Any pointers will help. Is to be done in R only

Comment: Please give a [mcve], i.e. edit your question!

Comment: Sorry! Forgive me this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taking thath your data frame is called "df"

```
l= list()
for (i in unique(df[, 2]))
   l[[i]]= df[, 1][df[, 2] == i]
```